# API results different response than SQL query

Tags: postgresql, api, rest, express

```js
const amIAvailable = (request, response) => {
    const { start_date, end_date, my_emp_id } = request.body;
    console.log(request.body, 'body')
    pool.query(
        `
        SELECT EXISTS (SELECT me.employee_id from (
            select counts.employee_id from
            (select e.employee_id, count(e.employee_id) review_count from emp_details_2 e 
                  left join project_allocation pa 
                  on e.employee_id = pa.employee_id 
                  left join project pr 
                  on pa.pid = pr.pid 
                  where pa.project_alloc_status='In Progress' AND pr.start_date NOT BETWEEN $1 AND $2
                  and pr.end_date NOT BETWEEN $1 AND $2
                  group by (e.employee_id))
                  counts 
                  inner join role_allocation ra 
                  on counts.employee_id = ra.employee_id 
                  where counts.review_count <= ra.inclusive_review) me
                  where me.employee_id = $3)
        `, [start_date, end_date, my_emp_id],
        (error, results) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }
            response.status(200).json(results.rows);
            console.log(results.rows, 'result')
        }
    );
};
```

I have written this API which is returning `false` for particular dates... But when I'm running this same query in pgadmin with same value parameters it's returning `true`

I'm not able to understand the behavior. Dates are in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the reason is the way that date strings are treated. Replace this query line

```sql
and pr.end_date NOT BETWEEN $1 AND $2
```

with this one (i.e. make string-to-date conversion explicit and controlled)

```sql
and pr.end_date NOT BETWEEN to_date($1, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND to_date($2, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

I would suggest that whenever dates, timestamps, time zones or encodings are concerned you always use explicit settings/rules and never rely on defaults.

Comment: Still same behavior. `{ start_date: '2-5-2021', end_date: '2-11-2021', employee_id: '12345' } ` for this pgadmin is returning true but API response is false.

Comment: But 2-5-2021 is not in `MM/DD/YYYY` format as you said above. What is it supposed to mean, 2 May or 5 February? This may be the reason - pgadmin and the API use different settings and treat it differently.

Comment: It's 5 February

Comment: So your date format is `mm-dd-yyyy`. Also pls. `console.log([start_date, end_date, my_emp_id])` to make sure that the runtime values are what you expect.

Comment: `{ start_date: '2-5-2021', end_date: '2-11-2021', employee_id: '12345' }` is when I console  `console.log(request.body)`

Comment: Okay.. When I returned `console.log([start_date, end_date, my_emp_id])` my_emp_id was undefined... Then I checked body console and it was actually `employee_id` and not `my_emp_id`. I feel stupid now. I spend hours debugging this man!